# when I submit redirect page based on select box when submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to redirect page after submit based on option url, I tried following code it not working is there any problem in this below code.

Please help me regarding this.

```
<div class="row">

<div class="wow fadeInLeft animated col-sm-12 col-md-12" data-wow-delay=".2s" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
<div class="san" style="padding:0px; ">

<div class="header-title">
<h3 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Donate Now </strong></h3>

<div class="hr hr-black"></div>
</div>
<br/> 
<form  id="comment-form1" name="contact-form1"  onsubmit="return mysubmit();">
<input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="Your Name.." required>
<input type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Your Email.."required>
<input type="text"  name="phone" placeholder="Your 10 digit Phone.."require pattern="[0-9]{10}">

<select  id="option" class="chosen" style="width:500px;">
<option selected disabled>Select Bank</option>
<option value="netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/?_ga=2.196148587.673827790.1549438128-1636006557.1549438128">Hdfc Bank</option>
<option value="www.icicibank.com/safe-online-banking/safe-online-banking.page?itm=nli_hp_0_btn_ib_loginbtn" >ICICI Bank</option>
<option value="netbanking.canarabank.in/entry/ENULogin.jsp" >Canara Bank</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>
<br/><br/>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function mysubmit(){
  //you can return false; here to prevent the form being submitted
  //useful if you want to validate the form

  window.location.href='https://'+document.getElementById('option').value;
}
</script>

</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: There are no call for mysubmit function

Comment: Instead of changing the window location try to submit the form like 
document.getElementById('comment-form1').setAttribute('action', document.getElementById('option').value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)**

```js
document.getElementById('comment-form1').addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
 e.preventDefault();
 window.location = ('https://'+document.getElementById('option').value);
})
```

```html
<div class="row">

<div class="wow fadeInLeft animated col-sm-12 col-md-12" data-wow-delay=".2s" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
<div class="san" style="padding:0px; ">

<div class="header-title">
<h3 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Donate Now </strong></h3>

<div class="hr hr-black"></div>
</div>
<br/> 
<form id="comment-form1" name="contact-form1">
<input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="Your Name.." required>
<input type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Your Email.."required>
<input type="text"  name="phone" placeholder="Your 10 digit Phone.."require pattern="[0-9]{10}">

<select  id="option" class="chosen" style="width:500px;">
<option selected disabled>Select Bank</option>
<option value="netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/?_ga=2.196148587.673827790.1549438128-1636006557.1549438128">Hdfc Bank</option>
<option value="www.icicibank.com/safe-online-banking/safe-online-banking.page?itm=nli_hp_0_btn_ib_loginbtn" >ICICI Bank</option>
<option value="netbanking.canarabank.in/entry/ENULogin.jsp" >Canara Bank</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
</form>
<br/><br/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: at the same time will i get those form information to mail using php mail function

Comment: @sansan i don't know much about `php` so can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` in your js function, `onsubmit` by default receives true which actually brings you back on the same page.

```
<script>
function mysubmit(){
  window.location.href='https://'+document.getElementById('option').value;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

or you can change the type to button and trigger this function on button click

`<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick=' mysubmit()' /><br>`

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking can't be done. When a form gets submitted it essentially redirects (using a get or post) to the defined action url. If you cancel the redirect then, the form will not get submitted as the redirecting is what sends/requests the data from the server.

There are two ways I can think of solving this problem.

1. Cancel the form submission and instead send an ajax request. once the response is received then you can redirect.

```js
var form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
var redirectElement = document.querySelector("#selectRedirect");
form.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);

function onSubmit(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    context: JSON.stringify(new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))),
    method: form.method.toUpperCase()
  }).done(redirect);
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function redirect() {
  window.location.href = redirectElement.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectRedirect">
  <option selected disabled>Select URL</option>
  <option value="url_1">URL 1</option>
  <option value="url_2">URL 2</option>
  <option value="url_3">URL 3</option>
</select>
<form id="myForm" action="action_url" method="action_get_or_post">
  <input type="text" name="somedata" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

2. Store the url in localStorage, cookies or url params and then redirect after the redirect. To do this using url params, just add a name like `redirectTo` to the select element, and then use this script.

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") onLoad();
else addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);

function onLoad() {
  var redirectTo = getUrlParameter("redirectTo");
  if (redirectTo) window.location.href = redirectTo;
}

function getUrlParameter(parameterName) {
  return (new RegExp(parameterName + "=([^&]+)", "i").exec(document.URL) || [])[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `mysubmit()` and I created an on-submit event using jQuery:

```js
 $("#comment-form1").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'https://' + document.getElementById('option').value;
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

<div class="wow fadeInLeft animated col-sm-12 col-md-12" data-wow-delay=".2s" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
<div class="san" style="padding:0px; ">

<div class="header-title">
<h3 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Donate Now </strong></h3>

<div class="hr hr-black"></div>
</div>
<br/> 
<form  id="comment-form1" name="contact-form1">
<input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="Your Name.." required>
<input type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Your Email.."required>
<input type="text"  name="phone" placeholder="Your 10 digit Phone.."require pattern="[0-9]{10}">

<select  id="option" class="chosen" style="width:500px;">
<option selected disabled>Select Bank</option>
<option value="netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/?_ga=2.196148587.673827790.1549438128-1636006557.1549438128">Hdfc Bank</option>
<option value="www.icicibank.com/safe-online-banking/safe-online-banking.page?itm=nli_hp_0_btn_ib_loginbtn" >ICICI Bank</option>
<option value="netbanking.canarabank.in/entry/ENULogin.jsp" >Canara Bank</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>
<br/><br/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</section>
```